# Ionic: 'Http' is declared but never used

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tslint

I've looked at a lot of these types of questions and answers on SO and haven't come across one that matches my issue; most are either "don't set Http to private" or "set `"noUnusedLocals": false` in tsconfig.json."

Neither of these help me (I've tried both, and more), as `Http` is set to public in my constructor and I don't want to just turn off these messages and ignore everything incase there is actually a problem somewhere.

So my warning when running `ionic serve` is:

```
tslint: src/providers/api.ts, line: 4 
Http is declared but never used.
```

Here is line 4

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

Here's my constructor in api.ts:

```
constructor(
    public config: Config,
    private network: Network,
    private toast: ToastController,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController,
    public http: Http,
    public storage: Storage,
) { ... }
```

And inside the function in api.ts I'm calling it like so:

```
getDataFromApi() {
    ...
    this.http.post(this.url, body, headers) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now, api.ts is a provider, so I'm calling the function from another page in my app, like so

```
this.api.getDataFromApi();
```

Everything is working just fine, except I'm receiving that error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show your import (line 4 of API.ts)

Comment: @David `import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';`